# JavaFX Background Color of Stage?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

What is the background color of stage in javafx? I want to set it to the background color of my textfield so they will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. It's in the CSS. It's "whitesmoke".